# Replace character with a number sequence in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, sequence

I have a huge text file with following pattern which has been repeated till to the end of the file:

```
--- 3DModelImport
        ModelKey    nvarchar
        TagNo   nvarchar
        Type    nvarchar
        LocationDwg nvarchar
        SignalType  nvarchar
        JunctionBoxNo   nvarchar
        PlantXYZ    nvarchar
        RowGuidID   uniqueidentifier

--- 3DModelInterface
        DbKey   int
        TagNo   nvarchar
        AreaUnit    nvarchar
        Type    nvarchar
        Description nvarchar
        ParentDbKey int
        SignalType  nvarchar
        JunctionBoxKey  int
        LocationDwg nvarchar
        PlantCoordX real
        PlantCoordY real
        PlantCoordZ real
        ModelKey    nvarchar
        SizeX   real
        SizeY   real
        SizeZ   real
        FromDb  datetime
        From3DModel datetime
        psize_ts    timestamp
        RowGuidID   uniqueidentifier

--- AccessTypeEnum
        AccessTypeEnumID    int
        Description nvarchar
        RowGuidID   uniqueidentifier
```

What I need to do is to replace all '**---**' with a number sequence starting from 1 and incremented by 1 i.e.:

```
1- 3DModelImport
        ModelKey    nvarchar
        TagNo   nvarchar
        Type    nvarchar
        LocationDwg nvarchar
        SignalType  nvarchar
        JunctionBoxNo   nvarchar
        PlantXYZ    nvarchar
        RowGuidID   uniqueidentifier

2- 3DModelInterface
        DbKey   int
        TagNo   nvarchar
        AreaUnit    nvarchar
        Type    nvarchar
        Description nvarchar
        ParentDbKey int
        SignalType  nvarchar
        JunctionBoxKey  int
        LocationDwg nvarchar
        PlantCoordX real
        PlantCoordY real
        PlantCoordZ real
        ModelKey    nvarchar
        SizeX   real
        SizeY   real
        SizeZ   real
        FromDb  datetime
        From3DModel datetime
        psize_ts    timestamp
        RowGuidID   uniqueidentifier

3- AccessTypeEnum
        AccessTypeEnumID    int
        Description nvarchar
        RowGuidID   uniqueidentifier
```

Comment: Write a shell/perl script to do this. I doubt any such feature will exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a one-by-one replacement:

Enter the dash in Find:

```
---
```

Enter the first number in Replace:

```
1-
```

Use <kbd>Alt+R</kbd> to replace. This will keep focus in the Replace field, allowing you the change the number easily.

Use a macro to record this for future reference.

**References**

- [Notepad++ Docs: Macros](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros)
- [Notepad++ Docs: Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)